# ansible assign a the value of the dict key if it match element from the list of dict value

Tags: ansible

I try to assign by "set_fact" the value the key corresponding to element in the list of value
ex:

```
 variable_ansible:
       key1: value1
       key2: 
        - value2-1
        - value2-2
        - value2-3
       key3:
        - value3-1
        - value3-2
```

if i give as input : value2-3 , this give me key2 as output
any idea please

Answer (score 0):

Make the dictionary consistent and put also 'value1' into the list, e.g.

```yaml
    variable_ansible:
       key1:
         - value1
       key2: 
         - value2-1
         - value2-2
         - value2-3
       key3:
         - value3-1
         - value3-2
```

Use *json_query*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _keys: "{{ variable_ansible|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        input: value2-3
        query: "[?contains(value, '{{ input }}')].key"
```

gives

```yaml
  _keys:
  - key2
```

The result of *json_query* is always a list because there might be more keys that fulfill the condition.